# Need to reduce the Wordpress Post Excerpt

Tags: wordpress

I am not a WordPress coding expert but I need help from the WordPress experts.

I am using a plugin that creates a Shortcode for posts on the other page. But when i use the shortcode for post, Excerpt is too long but i want to reduce it to 23 words. Can anybody help me how to fix it. Check the URLS.

- https://uk49predictions.com/uk-49-predictions/lunchtime-prediction/
- https://uk49predictions.com/uk-49-predictions/teatime-predictions/

Screenshot of posts with overflowing excerpt

[image: 2]

The plugin is called Shortcodes Ultimate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “shortcode”? Generally, that means a short URL for sharing to other sites, which doesn’t sound related to excerpt length. It would also help if you could provide links to the WP plugins you’re using.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reduce the excerpt length size via coding and als tell me where code should be add?

Comment: Plugin name is shortcode ultimate.

Comment: If you search the web for "wordpress how to reduce post excerpt length" you will find a treasure trove of solutions, including code and where to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of text lines with css, add this to `style.css` (Recommended):

```
.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-excerpt p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or, you can change the length of the WordPress excerpt by adding this code to `functions.php`:

```
function theme_slug_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
                return $length;
        }
        return 23;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'theme_slug_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using the Posts widget, you just need to pick a different template or create a custom template. Check out the docs for that [here](https://getshortcodes.com/docs/posts/).

Comment: Thank You...may be it will be helpful for me.